# Laravel Eloquent GroupBy Many To One Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, group-by

I have the below table structure :

user table

| id | name | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user 1 | 4 |
| 2 | user 2 | 2 |
| 3 | user 3 | 2 |

special_user table

| id | user_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

orders table

| id | user_id | provider | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Provider 1 | 10 | 16-01-2021 |
| 2 | 2 | Provider 2 | 20 | 16-01-2021 |
| 3 | 3 | Provider 1 | 10 | 16-01-2021 |
| 4 | 3 | Provider 1 | 50 | 16-01-2021 |
| 5 | 1 | Provider 3 | 15 | 16-01-2021 |
| 6 | 2 | Provider 1 | 20 | 16-01-2021 |

the output HTML table i want in the blade is  (for  16-01-2021)

| Provider | Users(amount) | Special User (amount) | Total Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Provider 1 | 1 ($60) | 2 ($30) | $90 |
| Provider 2 | 0 ($0) | 1 ($20) | $20 |
| Provider 3 | 0 ($0) | 1 ($15) | $15 |

the **Users** are user counts that their ID is NOT in special_user table .

the **Special User** are special user counts that their user_id is IN special_user table

the **(amount)** is the sum of the order amount of each type of user

the **Total Amount** is the sum of both the user amount and the special user amount .

Below is the code that i have tried :

```
$top_providers = Orders::
        whereNotNull('provider)
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_1, $end_1])
        ->groupBy('provider')
        ->selectRaw('*, count(*) as total_trans, count(transactions.user_id) as 
        all_users_count')
        ->get();
```

the above code group the orders based on the provider truly but i cant group the user types .

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: i have formatted the table , Please help !!!

Comment: What i am unable to get is the User and Special User columns

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired result set you can perform 2 queries, one will get the special user's ids and second will be using these ids to bifurcate between users

In plain SQL the query would look like

```
select 
  provider,
  sum(case when user_id not in(1,2) then 1 else 0 end) user_count,
  sum(case when user_id not in(1,2) then amount else 0 end) user_amount,
  sum(case when user_id in(1,2) then 1 else 0 end) special_user_count,
  sum(case when user_id in(1,2) then amount else 0 end) special_user_amount,
  sum(amount) total
from orders
group by provider
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26c37/2)

In laravel you can use query builder with raw method

```
$specialUserIds = SpecialUsers::where('status' , 1)->pluck('user_id')->toArray();


$orders = DB::table('orders')
            ->select('provider',
                DB::raw('sum(case when user_id not in('.$specialUserIds.') then 1 else 0 end) user_count'),
                DB::raw('sum(case when user_id not in('.$specialUserIds.') then amount else 0 end) user_amount'),
                DB::raw('sum(case when user_id in('.$specialUserIds.') then 1 else 0 end) special_user_count'),
                DB::raw('sum(case when user_id in('.$specialUserIds.') then amount else 0 end) special_user_amount'),
                DB::raw('sum(amount) total')
            )
            ->whereNotNull('provider')
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_1, $end_1])
            ->groupBy('provider')
            ->get();
```

Or you can use parameter binding using [selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#selectraw)

Also if there will be only one row in special user table for a user I would suggest to move that status attribute in your main user table instead of creating 2 tables with a one to one relation